# How to check cookie existence in .net framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, arrays, cookies, .net-2.0

I've used this code to check if some cookie exists in request:

```
if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("action")
```

But this code does not work in .net framework 2.0 since `System.Array` does not contain a definition for `Contains`.
What is the most simple thing to do this other than iterating through `AllKeys`?

Comment: Can't you convert that into a list. `Request.Cookies.AllKeys.ToList().Contains("action")`

Comment: @JeevanJose It seems not.

Comment: Oh. DGibbs' solution seems the cleanest one if that works. You should try that. If it doesn't then try using LINQ.

Comment: @JeevanJose .net framework 2.0 does not have linq either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it on the [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525394%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) collection itself by using the name as an index and avoid having to access `AllKeys`:

```
 if (Request.Cookies["action"] != null)
```

Comment: Are you sure it would not throw an exception?